# Java Object to Object Mapping in JAVA

Tags: java, object, mapping, pojo

Hi I have two classes like below.

```
class A{
    String name;
    String roll;
    int mark;
}

class B{
    String name;
    String roll;
    List<Integer> marks;
}
```

Now i have the List of Class A and I have to map with Class B.

```
List<A> scores;
```

Exmple: In Class A, I have Objects as

```
name:Rajesh,roll:10001,mark:100
name:Rajesh,roll:10001,mark:200
name:Rajesh,roll:10001,mark:300
```

But I have to move this data to Class B in the below format

```
name:Rajesh,roll:10001,marks:[100,200,300]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i dont realy understand your probleme but i know you want that :

```
B classB = new B();
classB.name = scores.get(0).name;
classB.roll= scores.get(0).roll;
classB.marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(A score:scores){
    classB.marks.add(score.mark);
}
```